# Multi scanner (Problems with asynchronous communication in Delphi10)

Tags: delphi

We have some Delphi applications developed with Delphi 2007 and even older.
We use serial communications, which we needed to be asynchronous, which is why we aquired AsyncPro a long while ago. We've been using APDDataPackets for ages, and it worked fine.

Now, we have been asked to migrate to Delphi 10.2 Tokyo, and nearly everything is going as expected (with conversions of string to AnsiString, Char to AnsiChar and so on).

The problem has arised with data packets, we don't get them to receive packets.
Our messages have a start byte ($02) and an end byte ($0D), which are specified in the ApdDataPacket.

Is there a structural problem with this component? Is there a modifification we must carry out on the components (ApdWinsockPort & ApdDataPacket) in order to get it up and running?
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Which version of AsyncPro are you using? See GetIt or [TurboPack-Tokyo/AsyncPro](https://github.com/TurboPack-Tokyo/AsyncPro) for the latest version.

Comment: @LURD we are using the AsyncPro 5.00

Comment: That is a 7-8 years old version, where `TAdpDataPackets` is not upgraded for unicode. I suggest to look into a more modern version. See ver 5 docs: [Installing TurboPower AsyncPro into Delphi XE and C++Builder XE](https://www.embarcadero.com/images/dm/technical-papers/installing-asyncpro-into-delphi-xe-and-c++builder-xe.pdf). *the following 6 components have been upgraded
for Unicode compatibility.
1. TApdComPort
2. TApdSLController
3. TApdStatusLight
4. TAPDTapiDevice
5. TApdTapiLog
6. TApdTapiStatus*

Comment: @LURD Sorry you might be answering to my previous message where i said i was using 1.3 ( it was a mistake from my part and it's the ver 5.0 , the one you actually pointed me towards, and because i couldn't edit the comment i deleted it ).About what you are saying right now ,If we can't use datapackets how can i receive messages only with the comport?

Comment: No, ver 5.0 is the old one. The one I linked to in my first comment is the latest. (You also can install it directly into the IDE from tools|GetIt). I don't know how the version numbering is done, but the current maintainer, Roman Kassebaum, can be reached for more info.

Comment: @LURD ok , I uninstalled the asyncpro component and then reinstalled it from the doc you just linked , the problem persist , i'm unable to use datapackets to communicate with my devices properly , the messages seem to be sent correctly but there is no response.

Comment: Ok, then you need to contact Roman for a possible solution. This question is too broad to fit here on SO. You could also test if someone on g+  Delphi Developers Group can give further advice.